# Loop a list to the N element

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Say i want to loop a list to the 10th element of said list. Can you tell me why code doesn't work?

```
loop <- function (list) {
  for (i in (list:list[[10]])) {
    df_i <- import(paste0(i))
  }
}
loop(list)
```

It returns:

```
Error in ord_dirs:ord_dirs[[10]] : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In ord_dirs:ord_dirs[[10]] :
  numerical expression has 18 elements: only the first used
2: In pasardir(ord_dirs) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In pasardir(ord_dirs) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: The `list:list[[10]]` should be `for i in in 1:10) {list[[i]]}`

Comment: Also, the `i` in the name `df_i` won't change as `i` changes, just like if I have a variable named `data` and I set `a <- "hello"`, it doesn't become `dhellothello`. You should probably put your results in a `list`. Perhaps `df_list <- lapply(list[1:10], import)`... but it's hard to tell. Is `list` actually of class `list`, or is it a character vector of filepaths, or something else?

Comment: I'd suggest reading my answer at [How do I make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207) for discussion and examples.

Comment: list is a character vector yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
loop <- function(list, x = 10) {

  df <- as.list(rep(NA, x))

  for (i in 1:x) {
    df[i] <- list[i]
  }

  df

}

list <- letters

loop(list)
```

Comment: This looks like a verbose way to do `df <- list[1:10]`... I don't think that's what OP's goal is.

Comment: Indeed, but `list[i]` can be replaced with `import` or whatever function is needed to achieve their goal.